# ObjectContext update an object from a detached state

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, objectcontext

I have an ObjectContext with an update method.  The method takes a generic object as a parameter.  I need to attach this object to the ObjectContext and update the database with the changes the object had.  example, I create a new object that has the same key as and entity in the database but some of the fields are different.  I want to attach the object to its corresponding entity in the database and have it save the changes the new object has. Here is what i have in the Update method:

```
public void Update(BaseObject data, entitySetName)
{
    AttachTo(entitySetName, data);
    Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, data);
    SaveChanges();
}
```

After the refresh, the data get overwritten by the fields from the database. Leaving out the refresh also does not update the database record. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DetectChanges() method will update the entitystate to modified if any changes have been made.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896269.aspx): "*In POCO entities without change-tracking proxies, the state of the modified properties changes to Modified when the DetectChanges method is called. After the changes are saved, the object state changes to Unchanged.*"

```
context.DetectChanges();
```

Additionally you could just set the state to modified so your method always trys to update regardless of whether anything has changed or not with:

```
ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(data, EntityState.Modified);
```

Comment: I added ApplyOriginalValues(entitySetName, data); after refresh, before refresh and removed refresh all with the same result as before where the updated values are replaced with the ones from the database.

Comment: I thought that did it anyway... I edited above. You can use Context.DetectChanges() before saving or telling the state manager that your data is modified.

Answer (score 1):

Use simply:

```
public void Update(BaseObject data, entitySetName)
{
    AttachTo(entitySetName, data);
    ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(data, EntityState.Modified);
    SaveChanges();
}
```